# function does not take 1 arguments error

Tags: c++, vector, arguments, enumerate

I've tried many times to fix this error but I'm not sure what to do. For both the addBooks and displayBooks functions I am getting a "function does not take 1 arguments" error, though the vector should just be one argument.

```
struct bookStruct
{
    char title[40];
    char author[40];
    int pages;
    int year;
};

enum menu { display=1, add, end} ;

void displayOptions();
void displayBooks();
void addBooks();

int main(){

    vector<bookStruct> book(1);
    string option = "display";

    displayOptions();
    cin >> option;

    //std::strcpy(book[0].title, "a");
    //std::strcpy(book[0].author, "a");
    //book[0].pages = 0;
    //book[0].year = 0;

    while (option != "end"){
        addBooks(book);
        displayBooks(book);
    }

    return 0;
}

void displayOptions(){

    cout << "1. Display list of books" << endl;
    cout << "2. Add books" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit" << endl;

}

void displayBooks(vector<bookStruct> book){
    for (int n = 0; n<book.size(); n++){
        cout << book[n].title << " ; " <<  book[n].author << " ; " 
            << book[n].pages << " ; " << book[n].year <<endl;

    }

    cout << endl;
}

void addBooks(vector<bookStruct> book){
    int n = book.size()+1;
    book.resize(book.size()+1);
    cout << "Enter the book title: " << endl;
    cin >> book[n].title;
    cout << "Enter the author name: " << endl;
    cin >> book[n].author;
    cout << "Enter the number of pages: " << endl;
    cin >> book[n].pages;
    cout << "Enter the publication year: " << endl;
    cin >> book[n].year;
}
```

Comment: Your function prototypes disagree with the implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Both `addBooks` and `displayBooks` take no arguments:

```
void displayBooks();
void addBooks();
```

yet you are calling them with arguments:

```
addBooks(book);
displayBooks(book);
```

The compiler is telling you this in its own words.

It looks like you need

```
void displayBooks(vector<bookStruct> book);
void addBooks(vector<bookStruct> book);
```

although it is more likely that you don't need to copy the vectors into the functions:

```
void displayBooks(const vector<bookStruct>& book);
void addBooks(const vector<bookStruct>& book);
```

**Note** you have definitions of one-parameter functions *after* `main()`. The `main()` function only considers the declarations that come *before* it.

Comment: note that he also defines the functions as taking arguments `void displayBooks(vector<bookStruct> book){` which is probably not correct..

Answer (score 1):

```
void displayBooks();
void addBooks();
```

take no parameter, however you passed `book` into them, the compile cannot find both functions. therefore, error.

Answer (score 1):

```
void displayBooks();
```

should be

```
void displayBooks(vector<bookStruct> book);
```

but as a better approach you can use:

```
void displayBooks(const vector<bookStruct> &book);
```

So that book vector is not copied while being passed into the method DisplayBooks

Comment: That should be a `const` ref to a `vector` since I guess `displayBooks` shouldn't need to store the data.

Comment: Didn't see he even had that in there originally.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared as

```
void addBooks();
```

but you are calling it with

```
addBooks(book);
```

Compiler obviously thinks it strange that you have no argument in the declaration, and then try to call it with an argument.

It is hard for me to advice exactly what you should do, since it's not clear from the code you have posted what the "right" thing is.

Comment: it's not that hard to advice, since he has the definitions under `main` - he most likely wants to have the vector as argument.